# What font is used on the cover of Boosey & Hawkes pocket scores?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I have consulted WhatTheFont!, Identifont, and FindMyFont, with pretty abysmal results. I would like to identify the font in the image below:
[image]
This is the cover of a pocket-sized orchestral study score, printed probably sometime between 1967 (the date of the copyright) and 1984 (date of purchase of this particular score). Boosey & Hawkes is a London publisher of study scores and other music.

Comment: That A-V kerning is beyond horrible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The english entry for [Gill Sans on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans) reveals some more information on the mysterious Q. It seems that both variants were used in different sizes of the historic metal-type version, at least for this specific *Title* variant.

> An American metal-type specimen sheet of **"Gill Title"**. Note the original "5", "7", "0", and "Q" in some sizes, which were dropped in many later metal type issues and digital versions, and a non-descending "J".
>
> [image: An American metal-type specimen sheet of "Gill Title".]

Answer (score 2):

On just a little bit of further research (a Google Image search on "sans serif Q with curly"), I can say with an amateur's confidence that this appears to be **Gill Sans**, though I've no idea what that modified Q tail means. Any enlightenment (or correction, if I'm wrong) appreciated.

Comment: That "Q" does not appear neither in variants, listed here https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/gill-sans/

Comment: @Mattia it does in the "shadowed" version https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/gill-sans/light-shadowed/glyphs.html

Answer (score 0):

It's Gill Sans with an alternative 'Q'. The current Gill Sans Nova digitisation [does include it](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/gill-sans-nova/medium/glyphs.html#glyphs/681100/1006).

That style of 'Q' was very normal in the nineteenth century, like on [Century Schoolbook](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/century-schoolbook/roman/glyphs.html), and the metal type version of Gill Sans included it (and [many other alternate characters](https://www.flickr.com/photos/stewf/25348920933)) which were available by special order. [Here it is in the introductory specimen](https://www.flickr.com/photos/36844288@N00/23553452720) along with an alternate R and J as well, but that sample still does show the normal Q we're used to as well. It might have been done to give printers a 'Q' that doesn't drop below the baseline at all if they wanted to give lines of capitals a more linear effect, like with the alternative 'J'.